# Using DTLS with socketserver (ThreadedUDPServer)

Tags: python-3.x, network-programming, socketserver, dtls

I am very new to network programming so please bear with me if I make newbie mistakes.

I have written a networking engine using ThreadedUDPServer from Python's socketserver library, which add layers of reliability to a certain level (UDP because this is primarily for a game server and I want to keep the performance and network overhead low with lightweight headers).

Now I want to secure it by using DTLS (attempting to use python3-dtls right now) but I'm not able to find any examples of this being done already. In the documentation for [python3-dtls](https://pypi.org/project/python3-dtls/), it is mentioned that it has been tested with ThreadedTCPServer *(this works because of PyDTLS’s emulation of connection-related calls)* but I have been unsuccessful in finding working implementations of the UDP equivalent.

I'm using the latest version of Python and no external libraries apart from this.

Any information or a nudge in the right direction will be greatly appreciated!